# Python/Arduino Serial communication

Tags: python, serialization, arduino

We are trying to communicate from Python to our Arduino, but are encountering an issue when writing to the serial port from python

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)

user_input = 'L'
while user_input != 'q':
    user_input = input('H = on, L = off, q = quit' )
    byte_command = user_input.encode()
    print(byte_command)
    ser.writelines(byte_command)   # This line gives us the error.
    time.sleep(0.5) # wait 0.5 seconds
print('q entered. Exiting the program')
ser.close()
```

The following is the error that we receive:

return len(data)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: you should provide the error you are getting

Comment: I have added the error in the original post. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/thingy.py", line 11, in <module>
    ser.writelines(byte_command)   # send a byte
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 558, in write
    return len(data)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works on my computer. I think the function you're trying to use (`writelines`) was added not that long ago to pyserial so maybe you are running on an outdated version.

In any case, as far as I know, `writelines` is inherited from the file handling class and you don't really need to use it for what you're trying to do. Actually I don't think it's even well documented

Just change it to:

```
ser.write(byte_command)
```

If you prefer you can see what version of pyserial you have and/or update.

To check your version run: `pip3 list | grep serial`

If you don't have version 3.4 you can update with: `pip3 install pyserial --upgrade`

Considering how `writelines` works for files (see, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720820/typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-int-python3)) your error might actually be related to the core Python you have (for your reference I'm running Python 3.7.3).

Answer (score 0):

[`writelines`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.writelines) accepts a list of strings so you can't use it to send a single string. Instead use [`write`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write):

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)

user_input = 'L'
while user_input != 'q':
    user_input = input('H = on, L = off, q = quit')
    byte_command = user_input.encode()
    print(byte_command)
    ser.write(byte_command)   # This line gives us the error.
    time.sleep(0.5)  # wait 0.5 seconds
print('q entered. Exiting the program')
ser.close()
```